# On Amazon Athena can I use compressed geospatial JSON data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gis, geospatial, amazon-athena

I'm using Athena to query some geospatial data encoded in GEOJSON. If I do it with uncompressed GEOJSON files, it works fine, but if I compress those files using gzip I get:

> HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens at [Source: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream@6acf4fe5: org.apache.hadoop.fs.BufferedFSInputStream@2793fa25; line: 1, column: 2]

Is it possible to use compressed geospatial data on Athena?

EDIT: As requested, here is the create table statement I used:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `locations`(
  `id` bigint COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `boundaryshape` binary COMMENT 'from deserializer')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'com.esri.hadoop.hive.serde.JsonSerde' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'com.esri.json.hadoop.EnclosedJsonInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://mydata/transformed/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='json', 
  'write.compression'='GZIP')
```

Comment: You need to create an external table in Athena and specify the appropriate SerDe (serializer/deserializer) and input format. For geospatial JSON data, you can use the open-source AthenaJSONSerDe or the built-in OPENJSON function to parse the JSON data.

You can then run SQL queries on the data, including geospatial queries, to extract insights and generate visualizations. You can also use Amazon QuickSight to visualize the data.

Comment: Can you share the CREATE TABLE syntax that you are using please? Specifically, confirm that you are using TABLE PROPERTIES ('compression_type'='gzip'). Given that you are getting an error in the first line it would seem that the file is not being interpreted as a gzip file.

Comment: Added my create table statement above. I have tried other variants on `write.compression`, such as `compression_type = gzip`and `compressionType=gzip` but it has not worked.

I suspect there is some formatting issue as Athena wants normal JSON when compressed to be a single row per line, but that is not possible with GeoJSON. I have tried putting the rows inside the `features` array on separate lines, but that hasn't helped